# Find two continuous, increasing functions $f,g$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ precisely when $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Find two continuous, increasing functions $f,g$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ precisely when $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

I'm pretty lost as to how to go about proving this. I feel like maybe it's going to be some sort of step function, but I'm not sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A step function isn't continuous. To make things easier, can you think of two functions that are 0 for every integer? Perhaps one function that is 0 for all integers and one function that kind of oscillates.

Comment: Play around with $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x+\sin x$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Why not make things simpler and subtract $x$ from $f$ and $g$ (I assume the second function is supposed to be $g$)?

Comment: @jef Second is $g$, yes. The functions have to be increasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is given by $f(x)=4x$ and $g(x)=4x+\sin (\pi x).$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- For $f(x) = \sin(\pi x)$ and $g(x) = -\sin(\pi x)$ you get that they are equal if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.
- The derivative for either of them is bounded by $-1$ from below, i.e. if you add strictly more, then it will become positive.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$